# parse_qs dont work on Django with Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using Django 1.11.5 and Python 3.5.2.

I wanna parse query string in this code but receive `No module named parse` Error.

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
qs = 'title=Test&recurring=weekly&description=Test Description'
data = parse_qs(qs)
```

This code works fine in Python 3.5.2 But in Django not work.

How to use parse_qs in Django ?

Comment: Is this related to django in any way? What happens if you run `import urllib.parse` in an interactive python session? Are you _sure_ you're running python 3?

Comment: on my local machine `Python 3.5.3` your code works fine

Comment: @Rawing  On Python 3 works fine. But in Django not work!

Comment: @BearBrown This code works fine in Python 3.5.2 But in Django not work.

Comment: please, show how do you run django? and how do you run python?

Comment: @BearBrown I deploy Django on Apache with Virtualenv and mod_wsgi.

Comment: Your Django must be using the system default version of python, which is not version 3.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's true. Problem solved. I create a new project by Virtualenv and use the system default version of python